# SystemError when attempting to create Excel spreadsheet for download from Flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-3.6, openpyxl

I'm attempting to create a temporary Excel file available for download via a Flask (v0.12) web application running on PythonAnywhere like so:

```
from io import BytesIO
from openpyxl import Workbook
from flask import send_file
from datetime import date

# ... Flask app here

# inside function/route serving Excel file
buffer = BytesIO()
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Sample"

# populate sample data
ws["A1"] = "some data"
ws["A2"] = str(date.today())

# send file to requestor
wb.save(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
return send_file(
    buffer,
    as_attachment=True,
    attachment_filename="{}_workbook.xlsx".format(str(date.today())),
    mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
)
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
SystemError: <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile> returned a result with an error set
```

I can't figure out how to work around this.

**Full traceback:**

```
2018-09-10 18:00:43,816: Error running WSGI application
2018-09-10 18:00:43,845: SystemError: <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile> returned a result with an error set
2018-09-10 18:00:43,846:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
2018-09-10 18:00:43,846:     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
2018-09-10 18:00:43,846: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,846:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
2018-09-10 18:00:43,846:     response = self.handle_exception(e)
2018-09-10 18:00:43,847: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,847:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
2018-09-10 18:00:43,847:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2018-09-10 18:00:43,847: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,847:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
2018-09-10 18:00:43,847:     raise value
2018-09-10 18:00:43,847: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,848:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2018-09-10 18:00:43,848:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2018-09-10 18:00:43,848: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,848:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
2018-09-10 18:00:43,848:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2018-09-10 18:00:43,848: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,848:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
2018-09-10 18:00:43,849:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2018-09-10 18:00:43,849: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,849:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
2018-09-10 18:00:43,849:     raise value
2018-09-10 18:00:43,849: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,849:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2018-09-10 18:00:43,849:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2018-09-10 18:00:43,850: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,850:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2018-09-10 18:00:43,850:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2018-09-10 18:00:43,850: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,850:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 228, in decorated_view
2018-09-10 18:00:43,850:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2018-09-10 18:00:43,851: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,851:   File "/home/ecwhitetailranch/public_html/app.py", line 1560, in inventory_report
2018-09-10 18:00:43,851:     return send_file(
2018-09-10 18:00:43,851: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,851:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 553, in send_file
2018-09-10 18:00:43,851:     data = wrap_file(request.environ, file)
2018-09-10 18:00:43,851: 
2018-09-10 18:00:43,852:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 726, in wrap_file
2018-09-10 18:00:43,852:     return environ.get('wsgi.file_wrapper', FileWrapper)(file, buffer_size)
```

Comment: This is the full stack trace?

Comment: @StephenRauch yes, from my error log (hence the timestamps). I know the traceback is less than helpful, hence hard for me to troubleshoot. I also can't seem to catch any exception except this full one.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can really pass an instance of BytesIO to uswgi. Try it with a tempfile and see if that's any better.

Comment: also what version of python is this?

Comment: @conrad Python 3.6 (see tags)

Comment: It turns out this is an issue with PythonAnywhere’s WSGI configuration which makes it so they do not support `send_file`. As much as I think it would be helpful to have this as an answer, this is now attracting DV’s so will likely just delete it. See https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/8612/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is with PythonAnywhere's uwsgi configuration concerning the `send_file` file wrapper in Python 3.5+. [This is a known issue.](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/8612/) [This issue](https://github.com/jessicabp/CapstoneServer/issues/24) is exactly what you tried it appears.

To fix this, you'd need to add the `wsgi-disable-file-wrapper=true` flag to the `uwsgi.ini` file (but I don't believe you have rights to do this on PythonAnywhere).